# Use Meijer-G function to represent elementary functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I want to represent these elementary functions: $x^{2}\sqrt{x}$, $\sin{4x}$, and $x\ln{x}$ as cases of `MeijerG`. What arguments should I give to `MeijerG` to get these elementary functions?

For reference, SymPy is able to represent them.
http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/modules/integrals/g-functions.html

Comment: Why do you go through the stage of the integration?  Why not merely ask (for your first question) how to express $a\ x^{3.5}$ in terms of `MeijerG`?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no argument that available in "MeijerG" to represent the integrand in MeijerG form.

Comment: I do not know of a direct Mathematica conversion routine for this. Might get some help from e.g. [1](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Power/26/02/01/), [2](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sin/26/02/01/), [3](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/26/02/02/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partial answer using the reference that you provided:

```
Limit[b^-1 MeijerG[{{0}, {}}, {{0}, {}}, x^(-5/2)/b], b -> 0]

(*  x^(5/2)  *)

Assuming[{x >= 0}, 
 Sqrt[π] MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{1/2}, {0}}, 4 x^2] // Simplify]

(*  Sin[4 x]  *)
```

Answer (score 7):

Version 11 now has the function `MeijerGReduce[]`, which returns equivalent `MeijerG[]` expressions in an inactive state. Applied to the OP's examples:

```
MeijerGReduce[{x^2, Sqrt[x], Sin[4 x], x Log[x]}, x]
   {x^2, Sqrt[x], 
    Sqrt[π] Inactive[MeijerG][{{}, {}}, {{1/2}, {0}}, 2 x, 1/2], 
    x (Inactive[MeijerG][{{1, 1}, {}}, {{1}, {0}}, x] - 
    Inactive[MeijerG][{{1, 1}, {}}, {{1}, {0}}, x, -1])}
```

where we see that only the last two functions were touched. The first two fail precisely because their Mellin transforms are not in a form suitable for the conversion:

```
MellinTransform[{x^2, Sqrt[x]}, x, s]
   {DiracDelta[2 + s], 2 DiracDelta[1 + 2 s]}
```

Contrast this with

```
MellinTransform[Sin[4 x], x, s]
   4^-s Gamma[s] Sin[(π s)/2]
```

In its current form, it does not seem to fit the style of [the defining Mellin-Barnes integral for Meijer $G$](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG1/02/), but using [the reflection formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.E3) and the [duplication formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.E5) for the gamma function, we have the identity

```
4^-s Gamma[s] Sin[(π s)/2] == 
Sqrt[π]/2 Gamma[1/2 + s/2]/Gamma[1 - s/2] 2^-s // FullSimplify
   True
```

which can now be compared with the $G$ expression returned by `MeijerGReduce[]`: `Sqrt[π] MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{1/2}, {0}}, 2 x, 1/2]`.

Answer (score 5):

There is an undocumented(!) function that essentially performs a [Mellin transform](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MellinTransform.html) through lookup. In your case, however, only one of your four examples actually has a sensible Mellin transform (and thus, a Meijer $G$ representation):

```
Integrate[Log[x], {x, 0, 1}]; (* force autoloading of the internal function *)

Integrate`ImproperDump`Mellin[Sin[4 x], x]
   (* Sqrt[Pi] Integrate`ImproperDump`MeijerGfunction[{}, {}, {1/2}, {0}, 4 x^2] *)
```

Check:

```
Simplify[% /. Integrate`ImproperDump`MeijerGfunction[a_, b_, c_, d_, z_] :>
         MeijerG[{a, b}, {c, d}, z], x > 0]
   (* Sin[4 x] *)
```

Try a more elaborate example:

```
Integrate`ImproperDump`Mellin[Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, -1/3, 1, x], x]
   (* Integrate`ImproperDump`MeijerGfunction[{4/3, 1/2}, {}, {0}, {0}, -x]/(Sqrt[Pi] Gamma[-1/3]) *)
```

As it is a lookup-based function, it might return unevaluated on functions that nevertheless have a $G$ function representation:

```
Integrate`ImproperDump`Mellin[Log[1 + x]/x, x]
   (* Integrate`ImproperDump`Mellin[Log[1 + x]/x, x] *)

MeijerG[{{0, 0}, {}}, {{0}, {-1}}, x]
   (* Log[1 + x]/x *)
```